# get first array of a 3 dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

given the following 3 dimensional array as an example:

```
Array
(
[324] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [workid] => 324
                [wname] => Y quiero llegar a mÃ¡s / Para triunfar en la vÃ­a
                [recordingid] => 476
                [rname] => Y quiero llegar a mÃ¡s / Para triunfar en la vÃ­a
                [rsubname] => Fandangos sevillanos
            )

    )

[325] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [workid] => 325
                [wname] => Ya basta
                [recordingid] => 479
                [rname] => Ya basta
                [rsubname] => 
            )

    )

[326] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [workid] => 326
                [wname] => Y sin embargo te quiero
                [recordingid] => 563
                [rname] => Y sin embargo te quiero
                [rsubname] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [workid] => 326
                [wname] => Y sin embargo te quiero
                [recordingid] => 562
                [rname] => Y sin embargo te quiero
                [rsubname] => (continuaciÃ³n)
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [workid] => 326
                [wname] => Y sin embargo te quiero
                [recordingid] => 478
                [rname] => Y sin embargo te quiero
                [rsubname] => 
            )

    )
)
```

i want to pick the first array of the 3 dimensional array and assign it to another array, let's call it **$arr_first**

the outpout of **$arr_first** should look like this

```
Array
                (
                    [workid] => 324
                    [wname] => Y quiero llegar a mÃ¡s / Para triunfar en la vÃ­a
                    [recordingid] => 476
                    [rname] => Y quiero llegar a mÃ¡s / Para triunfar en la vÃ­a
                    [rsubname] => Fandangos sevillanos
                )
```

Sure i could loop through and get what i want. But i need to know What is the most elegant and fastest way to achieve this whithout looping the entire array?

EDIT:
The array is just an example... it's hard coded. The key values could change. So i need to get the first array independent on id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: (assuming `$old_array` is your 3-dim array)

```
$arr_first = array_merge(array(), reset(reset($old_array))); // merge with empty array to clone
print_r($arr_first);
```

Using `array_shift()` instead of `reset()` will also remove the first element from the array so notice that.

I've used `array_merge()` since you asked "and assign it to another array", however if you're ok with both arrays being the same one you can drop the `array_merge()` and stick to:

```
 $arr_first = reset(reset($old_array));
```

**[Check this working fiddle](https://eval.in/44449)**

Comment: same thing, im getting the error: Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\public_html\songbook\index.php on line 52

Comment: @Marco which is line 52?

Comment: the error is because i try to enclose two or more functions that deals with an array type of variable, php will return an error..

Comment: tried it, after fixing the php error, and this solution does return the last first array... thanks!!

Comment: @Marco Glad to help, sorry for the mess. do you want to post what worked for you so I'll add it to the answer?

Comment: if it helps, after researching the reset() function i've found another way of doing this in one step, with no php errors: $arr_first = current(reset($array));

Comment: @Marco beware of this.. it will not always work. it will work only if the internal pointer of the inner array is set to the first element

Comment: @Marco this also takes the element out of the array.. same as array_shift

Answer (score 0):

$arr_first = array_shift(array_values($array));

var_dump($arr_first);

This way you can get always first independent on id.

Comment: im getting this error: Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\public_html\songbook\index.php on line 48

Comment: ok the problem is that when i try to enclose two or more functions that deals with an array type of variable, php will return an error.. That beeing said, this solution returns the first 2 dimensional array.. i want to last array